# vscode rsync error: some files could not be trasferred (code 23) error

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, rsync

I'm running a deployment to EC2 using rsync.
Until a week ago, the deployment was working fine. Since August 3 or 4, I'm getting the following error.

It looks like an error for IOS deployment. I'm doing a website deployment. Not mobile.

My guess is that the problem started after I updated vscode.
Because when I deploy from my personal laptop (before the vscode update), I don't get the error.

If you have a solution, please share it.

The error wording is as follows
: rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's embarrassing, but I knew how to fix it.
When rsync moved the file, it didn't update the path.

rsync -avz --delete ${PROJECT_ROOT}/.env.local ${PACKAGE_DIR}/

I split .env.local into .env.development and .env.production.

I don't think it reflected that, so it couldn't find the path.

I hope you don't make the same mistake I did.